# SVG Object causing jQuery Error

Tags: jquery, object, svg

Although my code is functioning properly, I am receiving the following three jQuery errors:

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundClip' of undefined
  chrome-extension://cjabmdjcfcfdmffimndhafhblfmpjdpe/wax.js:1
- Uncaught ReferenceError: `jQuery is not defined`.
- Uncaught ReferenceError: `$ is not defined`.

I have narrowed it down to the embedded [svg](/questions/tagged/svg)Object in page because when I comment it out the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)errors go away. I am not doing anything with the [svg](/questions/tagged/svg)Object using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)and I know that my [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)is working properly even though the error says it isn't defined.

Please help! Here is a link to the site with the errors: http://roartheband.com/test/index.html. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not getting those errors on your website. Those sound like they belong to a Chrome extension you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

- **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundClip' of undefined
  chrome-extension://cjabmdjcfcfdmffimndhafhblfmpjdpe/wax.js:1:** The function only can set a property value when the element exists in the page.
- **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined:** In your code, you have a function that needs jQuery object.
- **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined:** The jQuery library wasn't loaded correctly in the page.

BTW, your page is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Norton Security Toolbar extension that does this for me on Chrome.  Very very annoying!

It's an error with the extension and not your website which makes debugging really hard.